# DirectoryNotFound Exception in C#

Tags: c#, .net, path

I'm trying to save a file at path `WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\SaveFile`  but the following code returning me a "DirectoryNotFound" Exception with the message :

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'D:\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\SaveFile\Hello.tx

```
String Path = @".\SaveFile\Hello.txt";
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(Path);
if (!info.Exists)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = info.CreateText())
    {
        writer.WriteLine("HELLO");
    }
}
```

Could anyone please tell me how should I save a file at my desirable folder with specifying complete path?

Comment: So many levels of wrong.  How do you save a file to a folder if you don't want to specify the folder where you want to save the file?

Comment: I would like to save my file at "WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\SaveFile" folder with specifying fully qualifying URL.

Comment: @Stardust: Then you need to run the application with current directory set to "D:\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1".

Comment: You don't even attempt to verify the directory even exists before you write to it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are running in the debugger,  your default path is under `bin\Debug`. That's what "." means in your path.

Which folder do you want to save to? You'll need to specify the full path. Perhaps you'll want to pull the path from a config file. That way, the path will be able to change based on where your application is deployed.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message tells you the file will be saved in the subdirectory SaveFile under bin/debug. Before you can save a file you have to create a directory with Directory.CreateDirectory("SaveFile"). It will not be automatically created.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the directory exists prior to creating the text file.

```
String Path = @".\SaveFile\Hello.txt";
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(Path);
if (!info.Exists)
{
    if (!info.Directory.Exists)
        info.Directory.Create();

    using (StreamWriter writer = info.CreateText())
    {
        writer.WriteLine("HELLO");
    }
}
```